# Vue JS - How to get the index of elements outside of v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, for-loop, vuejs2

I want to know how one can get the index of elements outside the v-for

```
<template>
  <div class="hero-text">
      <h4>0{{ index + 1 }}/{{ homePageImageList.length }}</h4>
  </div>


  <VueSlickCarousel id="rar" v-bind="settings" ref="carousel">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in homePageImageList" :key="index" class="hero-image"
         :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + item.imageURL + ')' }">
    </div>
  </VueSlickCarousel>
</template>
```

Comment: Whats the use case?

Comment: *"How to get the index of elements here"* - which element?

Comment: In my real project there is a slider and a counter, every time you change the picture, the value of the counter is added one, or vice versa, the problem is that my counter must be outside the loop and now I need to get the index

Comment: I guess you could assign it into data within the scope of the li tag, but by the time a render happens, the value will be == elems.length-1.  It might be better to make an MRE out of the "real project"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "vue-slick-carousel" emits events. Check the [docs](https://github.com/gs-shop/vue-slick-carousel/blob/master/docs/API.md#events).
What you can use is `afterChange` which emits new `index`.

So in your case you can set this index in the `data`:

```
data() {
  return {
    currentIndex: 0,
  }
},
```

In the template:

```
<h4>0{{ currentIndex + 1 }}/{{ homePageImageList.length }}</h4>
```

And on the VueSlickCarousel

```
<VueSlickCarousel
  id="rar"
  v-bind="settings"
  ref="carousel"
  @after-change="currentIndex = $event"
>
  <div
    v-for="(item, index) in homePageImageList"
    :key="index" class="hero-image"
    :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + item.imageURL + ')' }"
  ></div>
</VueSlickCarousel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, you can't use the index of a loop outside it's scope.

As @dahn mentioned, you could use a local "counter" in your `data()`, so you can use it all over the component